# qmake issue when building: infinite building

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I've a very strange bug when I try to build with QtCreator.

When I try to build in the Compile Output I've this line repeated infinite times.

```
C:\Qt\5.1.0\mingw48_32\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ..\project\project.pro
```

I tryed to remove the build directory, but nothing. I've tryed to remove the *.user and regenerate them but nothing.

Does someone had the same problem?

Comment: The only method to resolve it was to unistall Qt and remove everything

Comment: you did not find any other solution? I found myself in same situation, but I don't want to be so radical:)

Comment: What version of QT are you using

Comment: Qt 5.2.0, Qt Creator 3.0.0. Somehow I can build projects again. I notice that my system has wrong date(it was set to date in past). I changed date to actual state and now everything seems to be in order. I tried to reproduce issue by setting date to past, but it wasn't fruitful. Maybe date is not connected with the problem. It confuses me a little.

Comment: I had the same problem with date in the past... The two things may be connected

Comment: To eliminate *unanswered* status of this question I decided to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Short:***
I had same problem and solved trouble by setting actual system date.

***Details:***
*(from conversations in comments)*

> I got same problem. Somehow I can build projects again. I notice that my system has wrong date (it was set to date in past). I changed date to actual state and now everything seems to be in the order. I tried to reproduce issue by setting date to past, but it wasn't fruitful.

Comment: Typically when posting an answer the idea is to collect all the relevant information there - IOW, you should probably quote your comment directly in the answer (expanding it if appropriate).

Answer (score 3):

The same problem occurs on my computer from time to time too. I found out it is caused by the .pro file having the file date-time in the future (due to some bug in syncing program).

Setting the .pro file time to now, for example by editing it in Qt Creator, solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this consistently for some of my projects. And all file timestamps were apparently valid.

I had to shorten file names (somes where huge) to fix the issue:
- Shortened project names (.pro) (file name and path, removed a few caracters)
- Shortened resources names (.qrc) (file name and path, removed a few caracters)

Issue then disappeared.

There's apparently a bug when file paths are too long (>~170, found [a post on a forum reporting that](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/59963-a-simple-project-with-quot-Infinite-building-quot)).

Also note that disabling "Shadow build" option was a good workaround: no infinite loop then (without shortening my file names). Probably because shadow-builds are using an output folder with a very long name.